# Rather than having a questions/answer count to meet fulfillment on a Stack Exchange, wouldn't it be better to use rep score?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment, commitment-fulfillment

I haven't had a lot of time to think this through the major possibilities, but it seems like it would be better to promote the asking of good questions (that receive up votes) and right answers (that receive up votes and/or acceptance) rather than just asking/answering 10 questions.

I'm thinking that a pure reputation score wouldn't work, but perhaps something like 3-5 questions/answers and 250 reputation to meet commitment. Or perhaps a scaling where n rep or m postings are equivalent to x "points" and you need y points to meet your commitment - a single really awesome question or answer might be fulfillment, but a larger number of OK or good questions/answers might be needed.

I'm also thinking about other, non-question/answer activity perhaps counting toward commitment. Upvoting, downvoting, commenting, getting upvotes on your comments, and participating on Meta to help define the community might be other ways that commitment to the community can be fulfilled.

Thoughts? Something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

By commitment you promise to provide questions and answers to the site in private beta period. Of course great questions are the most valuable, but the average are also important. Even the bad questions are useful - they help to define the site by showing how not to ask questions. You do not promise to ask great questions and give great answers, but you promise you will try.

But I think that reputation should be taken into account, but not in that sense, that there would be some level of reputation as extra requirement. Rather, the big reputation for a few great questions or answers should fulfill the commitment even if "the few" would normally be too few to fulfill it.